# Is the setRedirect function works in the model file of a component

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla1.7, joomla1.6

setRedirect doesn't works in the model file of a component.

models->test.php

```
$this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php', false));
```

Comment: I have find out the code to redirect from model file

`$app = JFactory::getApplication();

$app->Redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login', false));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Joomla 2.5 and Joomla 3.0

Redirection inside a model file:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->redirect(JRoute::_(JURI::root().'index.php'));
```

This redirection works in all files inside joomla, But the better way is to use in controller file is the below one.

Redirection inside a controller file:

```
$this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php', false));
```

In Joomla 1.6 and 1.7 use this for redirection inside model file:

```
global $mainframe;
$mainframe              =& JFactory::getApplication();
$mainframe->redirect($url, JText::_('Your Mail sent') );
```